# Parametrization of the Bumpy Torus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, parametrization

Find a parametrization of the bumpy torus, given as the set of points which have distance $5 + 2cos(7θ)$ from the circle $<10cos(θ), 10sin(θ), 0>$, where $θ$ is the angle occurring in cylindrical and spherical coordinates.

I got that $r = 10 + (5 + 2cos(7θ))cos(ϕ)$. Is this even right, and how to I proceed from here?

Comment: That looks OK,  but before we can answer the "how to proceed", maybe you should tell us what coordinate system you want to express the answer in. Apparently it's some sort of polar system, because you computed $r$. So: spherical polar? cylindrical polar? And for both, is the $z$ axis the one that points perpendicular to the $r/\theta$ plane?

Comment: It should be in spherical polar, and yes I think the z axis is the one that is perpendicular to the $r/θ$ plane.